# Is there a way to temporary stop a AWS Kinesis Stream?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-kinesis, amazon-kinesis-firehose

I have a following setup.

1. Kinesis Stream -> 2. Kinesis Firehose

Is there any way to stop 1. being active and re-enable it again later or the only solution is to delete it and recreate it back ?

Comment: A Kinesis stream is only "active" when something is pushing data into it. What's the _real_ problem that you're trying to solve?

Comment: It is billed per hour no matter if you use it or not, I was wondering if there is some mechanism to change status of the stream and return it back to active.

Comment: Maybe you can scale it to 0 shards. Not sure it's possible though.

Comment: @PhilippJohannis Minimum is 1

Answer (score 8, accepted):

there is no de-active/stop in kinesis you have to delete it and recreate later if you want [AWS doc] because charges accrue per stream whether you are putting and getting data with it or not.

Comment: This is a correct answer, but I cannot find any AWS docs mentioning that.

Comment: Do you know if firehose continues to charge money without an input data stream? If I delete data streams to cut down on costs.

Comment: @targetXING according to the pricing for firehose it doesn't appear to cost anything unless there's data

Comment: After playing around a bit, it seems like a rather bad idea to delete a data stream that has a firehose stream attached. The firehose stream will be suspended and getting it reconnected/recreated a) is complicated and b) comes with a warning from the documentation that the results are unpredictable.